# Reviving penalties

Tags: dnd-4e

My tiefling wizard died in the middle of the encounter while he had activated Wizard Wrath and Diabolic Transformation, and then used Arcane Rejuvenation to revive himself. My question is will he lose those powers or they still last until end of encounter ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you saved yourself with Arcane Rejuvenation (an immediate interrupt which heals you), your character did not die. He simply healed himself and then absorbed the attack. So there's no reason to assume any of his powers would be affected by this (any more than they would be by any other hit)

Comment: Right, the key is the word "interrupt", he healed _before_ the attack occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Everything Erik says is correct, but I suspect there's more confusion here that hasn't been cleared up. So please consider Erik's answer the correct answer for the question as written, and this a bit of a frame challenge, since the question hints at several rule misunderstandings.

**A character who falls below 0HP is not dead**

They're just unconscious. Characters do not die until they reach negative bloodied (half their HP), or fail three death saving throws while unconscious. There's ways to obtain exceptions to all of these rules, but these are the general rules in place.

**Arcane Rejuvenation triggers on falling below 0HP, not on dying**

As such, it helps prevent you from falling unconscious, not from dying, unless the triggering attack was going to deal more than half your HP in damage, in which case you may want to have a chat with your DM about the difficulty level of encounters (unless it was a crit from an elite/solo with a high-crit weapon, I suppose).

**Arcane Rejuvenation is an Immediate Interrupt, which means its healing occurs before the triggering damage**

This makes it substantially less useful, actually, because it acts essentially like THP, and if the damage from the attack exceeds the healing, you're still going to be knocked unconscious. If it were an Immediate Reaction, you could be knocked down and revive yourself back from negative HP, immediately resetting yourself to a positive HP value equal to the healing received. As-written, though, it just prevents the first Level+INTmod damage done.

**A character cannot legally have, much less use both the *Wizard's Wrath* and *Diabolic Transformation* powers, as they are mutually exclusive and both replace the tiefling *Infernal Wrath* racial ability**

The relevant feat text is as follows:

> Wizard's Wrath
>   Benefit: You ignore bloodied enemies’ fire resistance and fire immunity. **In addition, you replace infernal wrath with wizard’s wrath.**

and

> Diabolic Soul
>   Benefit: Whenever you take a critical hit, you gain a +2 feat bonus to attack rolls against that enemy until the end of the encounter. **In addition, you replace infernal wrath with diabolic transformation.**

Once you have replaced the Infernal Wrath power once, you cannot replace it again, because you no longer have it. A kind DM may allow you to take both feats and choose which to use on a per-encounter basis, but that would be a house-rule, as would allowing you to use both simultaneously.

To answer the original question, the relevant rules for powers ending prematurely are:

**If a character *dies,* all effects on her immediately end**

As discussed, it's relatively improbable that Arcane Rejuvenation will trigger in a way that prevents what would otherwise be an imminent death, but if it does, as an interrupt, you did not die, so no effects that end on death would end. Wizard's Wrath is not an effect *on* the character, it is an effect *imposed by* the character, so its duration (end of your next turn) is not dependent on your character surviving.

**If a character *falls unconscious* any power they are maintaining with the *stance keyword* immediately ends**

Diabolic Transformation has the *Polymorph* keyword, not the *stance* keyword, so does not end on KO, only on death.

Comment: I'm sorry i meant to say wizard's fury, not wrath.

Comment: And trigger for Arcane Rejuvenation is "You are reduced to 0 hp or fewer".